# Does angular-ui-select2 support aria-selected attribute?

Tags: css, ui-select2, angular-ui-select

Could you help me, I need to apply styles to selected item in select2 control. I'm using angular-ui-select2. In some examples I see that select2 indicates selected items with `aria-selected=true` attribute, but in my case there is nothing. Should it be switched on somehow or it is not supported yet?

I found this discussion while researching:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2499